# Must I keep mouse and keyboard plugged in

Tags: keyboard, peripherals

I'd like to install openelec on my pi2, after I have the pi the way I like it can i unplug my peripherals and have it boot up without kb/mouse

Comment: Have you tried it? It should not be a problem.

Answer (score 6):

> I'd like to install openelec on my pi2, after I have the pi the way I like it can i unplug my peripherals and have it boot up without kb/mouse

Yes.

Comment: Straight to the point. I like it